# How to protect your PHP website against common attacks in common frameworks such as Codeigniter/CAKEPHP/SYMFONY/ZEND

Tags: php, security

> Hi I am looking for advice regarding
>   protection and testing against attacks
>   on your php website.
>
> I have found some advice myself by
>   searching around and I hope the more
>   experienced developers have more
>   suggestions and can fill in the
>   blanks. please help out if you can so
>   we can make safer and better websites.

First some common attacks against websites:

**1. Server side:**
port scanning (1.1)

**2. websites:**
Cross-site scripting, (2.1)
Injection attacks, (2.2)
Cross-site request forgery, (2.3)
Broken authentication and session management, (2.4)
Insecure cryptographic storage, (2.5)
Insecure Communications, (2.6)
information Leakage (2.7)

**How to test:**

- 1.1 port scanning software (firefox has addons but they cannot scan low number ports?)
- 2.1 xss mefor firefox
- 2.2 inject me for firefox
- 2.3 xss me?
- 2.4 access me access me
- 2.5 ?
- 2.6 ?
- 2.7 ?

**how to fix in php (and preferably codeigniter,cakephp/symfony/zend):**

- 1.1 close your ports? (except for 80 and 465?)
- 2.1

`$config['global_xss_filtering'] = TRUE;`  *(codeigniter)*

- 2.2 use activerecord (escaping queries) *(codeigniter)*
- 2.3 ?
- 2.4 ?
- 2.5 ?
- 2.6 ?
- 2.7 ?

please help out if you can

thx

Comment: Your question is too broad to be answered definitively. Stack Overflow works when people ask specific, pointed questions about programming. For extended or subjective discussion on programming-related topics, try [Programmers.SE](http://programmers.stackexchange.com).

Comment: what if i point it down to one framwork such as codeigniter is it easier to answer? the points i have put out clearly suggests answers e.g. 2.1, 2.2?

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately security is much more than a list of tests. Before I continue on technical details you should first understand that the largest security issue is between keyboard and chair. So:

- Large random passwords, keep them secret
- Keep systems up-to-date
- Code with comments, structure, reviews and tests

For the server (assuming you use a linux/unix/bsd environment):

- Have a firewall, and a Intrusion Detection System
- Do close all unnecessary ports to the public, and if you need a port for yourself (like for ssh) add a firewall exception rule for it.
- Keep your operating system up-to-date, don't run personal stuff on it, don't go running experiments on it, don't run unstable
- Don't go with a shared hosting party
- Is your server located at a safe and secure spot?

You can test your application with all kind of security tools (like Nikto, Paros/Burp proxy, nmap, ...) but in fact since you wrote the application you can do a much better security test yourself.

- Using a framework with functions to escape variables in the layout layer of your application does prevent most XSS vulnerabilites, but be aware that escaping does not solve everything.
- Use session header to prevent XSS `httponly` (does not work in all browsers yet)
- Prevent SQL injection by using an layer that does filtering jobs for you
- Use autoloaders to prevent LFI and RFI
- Do not install other webapplications in your web directory and do not have testfiles hanging around
- Use captcha's to prevent bruteforcing to log-ins

There are also a lot more attacking vectors; probably to much for a regular developer to be aware of. Your application is secure by writing it secure and not by doing all sorts of tests. Use tests as a confirmation, in short: code secure.